# Why is my serial dispatch not working?

Tags: swift, core-data, synchronization, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch

I want to load some weather-data that is already stored in Core Data.
Obviously I want the collection view to update itself after the data is loaded. Can somebody tell me, why this code is not working?

```
let context = PersistanceService.context
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Weather> = Weather.fetchRequest()
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "loadanddisplay")
queue.sync {
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.weatherArray = result
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    } catch let err { print(err) }
}
```

When I manually reload the Data after this function has executed, it shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here did the job for me:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let context = PersistanceService.context
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Weather> = Weather.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.weatherArray = result
    } catch let err { print(err) }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = self.weatherArray.count
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Just make sure you call this correctly. I had to ready into how GCD works a lot to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Below block of code gets executed on background thread

```
queue.sync {}
```

and collection view is part of main thread or rather UI must be handled/updated from ***main*** thread only.

You can try something like below to reload collection view :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { // async OR sync as you want
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Obviously I have tried that first. Doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this line, I didn't understand what exactly you are doing here : When I manually reload the Data after this function has executed, it shows up.??

Comment: That means that reloadData() works when I create a button for that purpose. But it's not the best user experience to have to click a button for something that could be done automatic (or not in my case)

Comment: have you checked if your code is working without using  ***DispatchQueue*** ?

Comment: can you please post the code which you written on button click? I have implemented the same functionality while learning core java, I cross checked your code as well and I don't find any issue with your code.

Comment: The one on the button tap is exactly what you posted. Nevertheless it does not work if I just add it to the queue. Maybe I have to read into completion..